# How to retrieve a text from database with the breaks in the text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am working on vb.net web form and I am trying to figure out, how to insert breaks into a text that I retrieve from Microsoft Access (sql) database.

First I get some text in a web page.

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtboxExplanation" runat="server" Height="530px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px" MaxLength="600"></asp:TextBox>
```

There will be breaks in the text entered here. Then I send this to database when submitted.

```vb
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Explanations.mdb"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Title FROM Explanations;", con)
    con.Open()

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Title FROM Explanations;"
    Dim testID As String = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx")
End Sub
```

After that I go to another web page where I want to retreive this text from database and display it with the breaks in a label.

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Explanations.mdb"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Title FROM Explanations;", con)
    con.Open()
    lblTitle.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Explanation FROM Explanations;"
    lblExplanation.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

But this doesn't work. The lbl.Text simply ignores the breaks. How can I get around this issue?

Thanks very much for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view source from your browser on the label page, I suspect you'll see the carriage returns in your HTML.  To display the breaks in the label, you can either wrap it in a `<pre>` tag, or in your code behind, after you've set the label, add

`lblExplaination.Text = lblExplaination.Text.Replace(VbCrLf, "<br />")`

Comment: Adding that line worked perfectly. I kind of figured out I need to add some html after writing this post but I didn't know about predefined constants so thanks very much!

Comment: Glad it helped.  FYI, other alternatives to `VbCrLf` are
`System.Environment.NewLine` and `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`